# Sending Email from a Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, apex-email-service, lightning-apps

I know it's possible to use server side Apex to send out emails but not sure about Lightning Component. I have a lightning component which contains a list of users and the associated "Email this person" buttons so I was wondering if you have any suggestions to trigger the buttons to send a template email to the selected address.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have something from Lightning components trigger an email, you have some options.

#### Workflow

When a record is saved, you can use a workflow rule to trigger sending an email. If the save is done as a result of your component, then great. It still works.

#### Apex

Here you don't have to depend upon a record save. You can arbitrarily send email. But you are required to abide by the maximum outbound email limit.

#### Callout to External Email Service

Again, this is via Apex, but instead of using our email service, you could make a callout to an external email provider.

In the end, none of these really has anything to do with Lightning Components. Nor should they. Lightning Components is a client-side Javascript component framework. It runs in the browser/web view.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking if you can use Apex? If so, yes, Apex is the way that Lightning Components interact with the server. You can call a Lightning Action that maps to an Apex function, passing in the parameters to use for the email.

If this isn't what you're looking for, please provide further details.